# Flutter Cards - How to Loop a card widgets in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

**Main.dart**

I want to loop the cards in the flutter.Since in Angular 2 just *ngFor works fine now in same way how can i loop it.I don't found and docs on flutter web.
you will find the output in the screen shot 
Please help me to know how to loop cards or any other widgets

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home:new MyCard()
    );
  }
}
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget allcards;
      return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('My First App'),
              backgroundColor:new Color(0xFF673AB7),
            ),
            body: new Container(
              child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Card(
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Image.network('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg'),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                             new Padding(
                               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                               child: new Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                             ),
                             new Padding(
                               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                               child: new Text('Like',style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                             ),
                             new Padding(
                               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                               child: new Icon(Icons.comment),
                             ),
                             new Padding(
                               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                               child: new Text('Comments',style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                             )

                            ],
                          )
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),

            )

        );

    }
}`
```

This is my dart file 
screen shot 
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Just like Angular2* having an iteratable to loop over is what makes any loop works.

So I did some refactoring in your code and added a the list, changed `Column` with a `ListView` and here is the result:

[image]

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        home:new MyCard()
    );
  }
}
class MyCard extends StatelessWidget{
  List cards = new List.generate(20, (i)=>new CustomCard());
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text('My First App'),
              backgroundColor:new Color(0xFF673AB7),
            ),
            body: new Container(
              child: new ListView(
                children: cards,
              )

            )

        );

    }
}

class CustomCard extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
              return  new Card(
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Image.network('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/fq4N0hgOWzU/maxresdefault.jpg'),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                          child: new Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                             new Padding(
                               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                               child: new Icon(Icons.thumb_up),
                             ),
                             new Padding(
                               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                               child: new Text('Like',style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),),
                             ),
                             new Padding(
                               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                               child: new Icon(Icons.comment),
                             ),
                             new Padding(
                               padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                               child: new Text('Comments',style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),
                             )

                            ],
                          )
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
  }
}
```

Comment: Was throwing error while generating list. But after adding .toList(), its working fine. Don't why we need to add .toList( ). :/

Comment: Can you explain how did you add .toList() ?

Comment: Add .toList() to                                                                                                             
  

List cards = new List.generate(20, (i)=>new CustomCard()).toList();

Answer (score 1):

In case if any one gets error with above solution please add **`.toList()`** to

> **`List cards = new List.generate(20, (i)=>new CustomCard()).toList();`**

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid this error:

> This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not final:

Just put

> final

At this line:

> List cards = new List.generate(20, (i)=>new CustomCard());

Staying this:

> final List cards = new List.generate(20, (i)=>new CustomCard());